# ZFS: Is scrub safe to stop, if zpool seems to have both resilver and scrub happening concurrently after disk reinsertion?

Tags: ubuntu, zfs

I have an Ubuntu 20.04 server which is running ZFS with a 56TB disk array.

We have a disk marked as FAULTED. While trying to deal with this, we accidentally pulled out the  wrong disk, but put it back in. As such, we had the FAULTED disk as well as another one now marked OFFLINE. This means we are at the limit of redundancy now, so need to resolve this quickly.

We ran `zpool replace backups /dev/sdh /dev/sdh` (though apparently this should have been /dev/sdh1).

When I currently run `zpool status`, sometimes it indicates that a **resilver** is running, and other times a **scrub** is running - see below.

This has been running now for 4 days, and the '54.8T total' figure isn't changing. The 'in progress since' date always seems to be within a minute or two of the command being run.

Does this look wrong? Should I continue to wait, or is the best thing to do to stop the scrub using `zpool scrub -s backups`, or something else?

```
# zpool status
  pool: backups
 state: DEGRADED
status: One or more devices could not be used because the label is missing or
    invalid.  Sufficient replicas exist for the pool to continue
    functioning in a degraded state.
action: Replace the device using 'zpool replace'.
   see: http://zfsonlinux.org/msg/ZFS-8000-4J
  scan: scrub in progress since Tue May 11 20:18:22 2021
    3.03G scanned at 3.03G/s, 0B issued at 0B/s, 54.8T total
    0B repaired, 0.00% done, no estimated completion time
config:

    NAME                      STATE     READ WRITE CKSUM
    backups                   DEGRADED     0     0     0
      raidz2-0                DEGRADED     0     0     0
        sdi                   ONLINE       0     0     0
        sdj                   ONLINE       0     0     0
        sdk                   ONLINE       0     0     0
        sdc                   ONLINE       0     0     0
        sdd                   ONLINE       0     0     0
        11802105070547673345  FAULTED      0     0     0  was /dev/sde1
        sde                   ONLINE       0     0     0
        sdf                   ONLINE       0     0     0
        sdg                   ONLINE       0     0     0
        replacing-9           OFFLINE      0     0     0  all children offline
          old                 OFFLINE      3   816     0
          sdh                 OFFLINE      0     0     0

errors: No known data errors
```

```
# zpool status
  pool: backups
 state: DEGRADED
status: One or more devices could not be used because the label is missing or
    invalid.  Sufficient replicas exist for the pool to continue
    functioning in a degraded state.
action: Replace the device using 'zpool replace'.
   see: http://zfsonlinux.org/msg/ZFS-8000-4J
  scan: scrub in progress since Tue May 11 20:22:06 2021
    78.9G scanned at 9.86G/s, 357K issued at 44.6K/s, 54.8T total
    0B repaired, 0.00% done, no estimated completion time
config:

    NAME                      STATE     READ WRITE CKSUM
    backups                   DEGRADED     0     0     0
      raidz2-0                DEGRADED     0     0     0
        sdi                   ONLINE       0     0     0
        sdj                   ONLINE       0     0     0
        sdk                   ONLINE       0     0     0
        sdc                   ONLINE       0     0     0
        sdd                   ONLINE       0     0     0
        11802105070547673345  FAULTED      0     0     0  was /dev/sde1
        sde                   ONLINE       0     0     0
        sdf                   ONLINE       0     0     0
        sdg                   ONLINE       0     0     0
        replacing-9           OFFLINE      0     0     0  all children offline
          old                 OFFLINE      3   816     0
          sdh                 OFFLINE      0     0     0

errors: No known data errors
```